# PIR Sensor for bulb in room

Tags: power-supply, sensor, 5v, pir

This has been very long since I left electronics but recently I restarted taking interest in it as hobby.

I bought some PIR sensors from Aliexpress and found it is very simple to implement if I have 5V DC supply on breadboard. I am not sure how I can hook it up to bulb (CFL or 230V LED bulb) as a complete unit.

Can some tell me, should I use 5v DC normal AC-DC step down power supply enclosed everything in small box and mount it near the bulb or is there any other way to do it. I will use 5V relay and relay driver using NPN transistor.

I am asking this because all the tutorials I have seen uses breadboard power supply or 12V DC adapter and 5V regulator IC. I did not come across with real life application using 5v drawn from mains supply.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the PIR sensor that you're using? The advantage of having a 5V regulator on board is that you can be sure that you're giving the PIR module a clean 5V supply. PIR's are often very sensitive to electrical noise which gives false triggering. And don't use the 5V regulator to power the relay - power that from 12V.

Comment: This is a [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MOOL-5PCS-HC-SR501-Adjust-Ir-Pyroelectric-Infrared-PIR-Humen-Motion-Sensor-Detector-Modules-for-Arduino/32910515967.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.132e4c4dKy080r) from where I bought the PIR Sensor

Comment: And I may buy [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5V-700mA-3-5W-AC-DC-Precision-Buck-Converter-AC-220v-to-5v-DC-step-down/32677330307.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.23.42ae1223lMXdTc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536_10902,searchweb201603_60,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=8d4ee586-c69b-4006-937b-9d14a70f6d1f-3&algo_pvid=8d4ee586-c69b-4006-937b-9d14a70f6d1f) power supply for this module.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the Pir sensor can work from 5v to 20v. If your relays are 5v, I dont see any problem using an 5v power supply and power everything. You can use any USB charger that can provide enough current to power the whole circuit.

Comment: As I said, I know I can use USB charger but I can't pack that kind of power supply in a small enclosure and fix it near the bulb on a wall. I wanted use small AC-DC 5V DC normal full-wave rectifier. Have asked correct question. Is it quite simple, I can use?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.